# Internode Communication mechanism

Tags: java, cluster-computing

I am trying to make a Java cluster for learning purposes. I am going to use TCP for internode communication. The problem I am having is that I am not sure about how to connect to nodes.

Which means, let's say I have a 10 node cluster: does each and every node have to connect to all other nodes? If not, how is this done? How reliable is it?

Making a socket connection with each and every node looks pretty inefficient to me.

Can someone show me the right path?

Comment: [`MulticastSocket`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html)

Comment: does this require all the nodes being in the same subnet?

Comment: an As I know this is UDP rite? , so is it reliable for high availability?

Comment: Elliot talks about IP-Multicast, not related with UDP. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast. It is reliable for HA, although I suggest using a message broker, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid that each node connects to all other nodes with a unicast connection. If you would do that the number of required connections equals `(n²-n)`.

What you can do is multicast communication, e.g. with [Apache Tribes](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/tribes/introduction.html).
Multicast has disadvantages, e.g. all host have to be in the same subnet (unless you want to mess with the TTL field, which I suggest to avoid).

The other alternative would be to use a message broker like [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) or [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/). See also [JMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service). In this case each node establishs a regular unicast connection with the message broker and reads and writes to the message queue. In this case nodes may be in different subnets. I suggest to take a closer look at this option.